# Add additional OID root to default SNMP agent output on "bare" snmpwalk command

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

When executing the following command on a Brocade Vyatta 5600, you only get OIDs from a root OID of `.1.3.6.1.2.`

`snmpwalk -c XXXXXXX -v 2c vyatta01.foo.com`

However, the vendor specific OIDs are available only in the root OID `.1.3.6.1.4.`  I need to get these vendor OIDs when performing a "bare" snmpwalk as shown above.

I have a situation where I cannot change the command used to retrieve data, so I cannot simply add `.1.3.6.1.4` to the end of the snmpwalk command.  I also cannot change the SNMP agent (Net-SNMP) running on the Vyatta router.

I have considered using the SNMP agent extend or pass directives, but I'm not really sure how I would configure that.  In essence, I would like to be able to execute the `snmpwalk` and have it return OIDs from both the `.1.3.6.1.2` and `.1.3.6.1.4` roots.  I have used the deprecated "exec" directive to point to arbitrary OIDs to retrieve specific information, but in that case, I could specify a root OID.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did any of these answers help you ? Or do you need more info ?

Answer (score 0):

The manager (Netsnmp's `snmpwalk` command) rather than the agent is one specifying the OIDs to be walked. I don't think it makes sense for the agent to return different OIDs than is requested by the manager so any change needs to be on manager side.

`snmpwalk` man page says :

```
snmpwalk [APPLICATION OPTIONS] [COMMON OPTIONS] [OID]  

If no OID argument is present, snmpwalk will search the subtree rooted at 
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2 (including any MIB object values from other MIB modules, 
that are defined as lying within this subtree).
```

Comment: Backwards terminology here, the manager is the one requesting stuff from the agent.

Answer (score 0):

The agent is not properly arranging its OIDs in a lexicographical order, making it impossible for a manager to walk it from the root and still reach the whole MIB tree.

I've seen this happen with some vendors' extensions of the Windows SNMP agent, but apparently others can also make the same mistake. The error is firmly in the agent and needs to be fixed there, so do file a bug report to Brocade. However, a workaround can be implemented on the manager side, by doing separate `snmpwalk`s of each subtree. One walk for `.1.3.6.1.2` and one for `.1.3.6.1.4`.

It sounds very unfortunate that a network management framework would rely on the `snmpwalk` command towards the root OID. A proper NMS would have the flexibility to decide which OIDs are walked on an agent.

Maybe you could alias the `snmpwalk` command on your system? Write a wrapper script that checks the agent address, and if the agent is a Brocade, the wrapper can execute two snmpwalk commands and concatenate their output. It's a rather ugly hack, but it's all I can think of.